# Mysql or condition

Tags: php, mysql

How to properly use or in mysql query?

With the following query I'm trying to search for string in playlist_name and name, but it's ignoring the "playlist_name"

```
$search_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM show where playlist_name or name LIKE '%$search_string%'");
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_query, It's deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LIKE` for the first condition too

```
$search_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM show WHERE
playlist_name LIKE '%$search_string%' 
OR
name LIKE '%$search_string%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where playlist_name LIKE '%$search_string%' or name LIKE '%$search_string%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check condition for both fields.

```
where playlist_name LIKE '%$search_string%'" OR name LIKE '%$search_string%'"
```